# error obtaining VCS status: exit status 128 Use -buildvcs=false to disable VCS stamping

Tags: go, backend, grafana, go-build

I am trying to build back-end of Grafana with "go run build.go build" command in the grafana directory in CMD.
While building the back-end of Grafana, I get an error "error obtaining VCS status: exit status 128" and exit status 1

[error obtaining VCS status: exit status 128](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAPwf.png)

How to solve this problem?

I tried to build the back-end of Grafana with a command "go run build.go build" in cmd in the grafana directory.
I expected the grafana back-end would be built with no problem and I could access localhost:3000.
However, there was an error while building "[error obtaining VCS status: exit status 128](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOnzy.png)

Comment: IIRC, 128 is a catch-em-all error exit code for git in case of network problem. Look into your git situation closely.